# How to save API data locally in Flutter so that app can work without internet connection?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm developing a small Flutter application using https://newsapi.org/ API and Riverpod. I want to make my app work offline (when there is no internet connection). I'm confused in when/where to save the API response and where to retrieve it.

main.dart (EDITED)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pace_stock_internship_task/model/article_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'providers/providers.dart';
import 'screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'utility/size_config.dart';

import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

  Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(ArticleAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(SourceAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox('myarticles');
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
        child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
            darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              // scaffoldBackgroundColor: scaffoldBgColor,
            ),
            home: const HomeScreen())),
  );
}
```

article_model.dart

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
    
    part 'article_model.g.dart';
    
    @HiveType(typeId: 0)
    class Article {
      Article({
        this.source,
        this.author,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.url,
        this.urlToImage,
        this.publishedAt,
        this.content,
      });
    
      @HiveField(0)
      Source? source;
      @HiveField(1)
      String? author;
      @HiveField(2)
      String? title;
      @HiveField(3)
      String? description;
      @HiveField(4)
      String? url;
      @HiveField(5)
      String? urlToImage;
      @HiveField(6)
      String? publishedAt;
      @HiveField(7)
      String? content;
    
      factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Article(
            source: Source.fromJson(json["source"]),
            author: json["author"] ?? '',
            title: json["title"] ?? '',
            description: json["description"] ?? '',
            url: json["url"] ?? '',
            urlToImage: json["urlToImage"] ?? '',
            publishedAt: json["publishedAt"] ?? '',
            content: json["content"] ?? '',
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "source": source!.toJson(),
            "author": author ?? '',
            "title": title ?? '',
            "description": description ?? '',
            "url": url ?? '',
            "urlToImage": urlToImage ?? '',
            "publishedAt": publishedAt ?? '',
            "content": content ?? '',
          };
    }
    
    @HiveType(typeId: 1)
    class Source {
      Source({
        this.id,
        this.name,
      });
    
      @HiveField(0)
      String? id;
      @HiveField(1)
      String? name;
    
      factory Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Source(
            id: json["id"] ?? '',
            name: json["name"] ?? '',
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id ?? '',
            "name": name ?? '',
          };
    }
```

api_service.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../model/article_model.dart';

class ApiService {
  final String _endPoint =
      'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY';

  Future<List<Article>> getArticles() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_endPoint));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)["articles"];
      return result.map<Article>((e) => Article.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}

final apiProvider = Provider<ApiService>((ref) => ApiService());
```

I've written the logic for checking whether there is internet connection or not inside providers.dart.

providers.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../model/article_model.dart';
import '../services/api_service.dart';

enum NetworkStatus {
  on,
  off,
}

class NetworkDetectorNotifier extends StateNotifier<NetworkStatus> {
  late NetworkStatus newState;
  NetworkDetectorNotifier() : super(NetworkStatus.off) {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      switch (result) {
        case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
          newState = NetworkStatus.on;
          break;

        case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
          newState = NetworkStatus.on;
          break;
        case ConnectivityResult.none:
          newState = NetworkStatus.off;
          break;
        case ConnectivityResult.bluetooth:

        case ConnectivityResult.ethernet:

        case ConnectivityResult.vpn:
      }
      if (newState != state) {
        state = newState;
      }
    });
  }
}


final networkCheckProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<NetworkDetectorNotifier, NetworkStatus>(
        (_) => NetworkDetectorNotifier());

final articleProvider = FutureProvider<List<Article>>(
    (ref) async => await ref.watch(apiProvider).getArticles());
```

home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../constant/constants.dart';
import '../providers/providers.dart';
import '../utility/size_config.dart';
import 'details_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //SizeConfig().init(context);
    final articles = ref.watch(articlesProviderNew);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: scaffoldBgColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: appBarColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('HEADLINES',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: appBarTitleSize,
              color: appBarTitleColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            )),
      ),
      body: articles.when(
        data: ((articles) => ListView.builder(
              // padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0.0, 16, 24),
              itemCount: articles.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final article = articles[index];
                final date = DateFormat('yy-mm-dd').parse(article.publishedAt!);
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 16.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 24.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * .35,
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * .75,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: (() =>
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: ((context) => DetailsScreen(
                                    article: article,
                                  ))))),
                      child: Card(
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                        child: GridTile(
                          footer: GridTileBar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
                            title: Text(
                              article.title!,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: articleTitleTextSize,
                                color: articleTitleTextColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              '${article.author!}\t\t\t\t$date',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: authorTextSize,
                                color: authorTextColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/no_image.png'),
                                placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                imageUrl:
                                    articles.elementAt(index).urlToImage!),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )),
        error: ((error, stackTrace) {
          print('Error : $error\n$stackTrace');
          return Text('Error : $error\n$stackTrace');
        }),
        loading: () => const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

details_screen.dart

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../constant/constants.dart';
import '../model/article_model.dart';
import '../utility/size_config.dart';

class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key, required this.article}) : super(key: key);

  final Article article;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CachedNetworkImage(
            height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                Image.asset('assets/images/no_image.png'),
            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            imageUrl: article.urlToImage!),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              leading: Container(
                height: 42.0,
                width: 42.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1).withOpacity(.3)),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 42.0,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              )),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(leftPadding2),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text(
                  article.title!,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: appBarTitleSize, color: articleTitleTextColor),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: vertPadding,
                ),
                Row(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(article.author!,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: articleTitleTextSize,
                              color: articleTitleTextColor)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(article.publishedAt!,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: articleTitleTextSize,
                              color: articleTitleTextColor)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: vertPadding2,
                ),
                Text(article.content!,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: articleContentSize, color: authorTextColor))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to make my app work offline ?

Edit-: Following code I'm using for saving and retrieving API data, but I'm getting error while retrieving, that is type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>' .

```
final articlesProviderNew = FutureProvider<List<Article>>((ref) async {
  var articleBox = Hive.box('myarticles');
  var network = ref.watch(networkCheckProvider);

  switch (network) {
    case NetworkStatus.on:
      {
        List<Article> articles = await ref.watch(apiProvider).getArticles();
        var articleLS = articleBox.get('articleLS');
        if (articleLS == null || articleLS.isEmpty) {
          await articleBox.put('articleLS', articles);
        }

        return articles;
      }
    case NetworkStatus.off:
      {
        var articleLS = articleBox.get('articleLS');
        return articleLS;
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to check :
the first time ever you need to force user to have internet.
all data they will be stored in local memory for the first time then if the user will not have internet then you can get data from local memory.

```
class NetoworkCheck extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NetoworkCheck({super.key});
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    var network = ref.watch(networkCheckProvider);
    if (network == NetworkStatus.off) {
      return const NoNetworkScreen();
    }
    return const HomeScreen();
  }
}
```

you can check here
and put your code here for storing data

```
if (network == NetworkStatus.off) {
store all data
          return const NoNetworkScreen();
        }
```

don't forget to use async/await mostly it will tike some time to store data

Comment: Added code for saving API data using Hive but getting error. Please check it out.